# Number to string with leading (left padded) zeros in Julialang

Tags: string, julia, leading-zero

It seems as an easy question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere. If I have an integer variable, how can I transform it to a string with leading zeros?

I want something as the code below:

```
n = 4
string_size = 3
println(fleading(n, string_size)) 
# result should be "004"
```

Where `fleading` would be something like the function to transform the number to string with leading zeros. The analogous way in python is `str(4).zfill(3)` which gives `004` as result.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're looking for the `lpad()` (for left pad) function:

```
julia> lpad(4,3,"0")
"004"
```

Note the last argument must be a string.

From the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/strings/):

> **lpad(string, n, "p")**
>
> Make a string at least n columns wide when printed, by padding on the left
>   with copies of p.

Comment: Thanks! looking for leading zeros didn't get me any result.

Comment: @silgon Yeah, it's tricky to know all the different terminology people use to refer to this kind of stuff

Comment: Now it has to be `lpad(4,3,"0")` as the last one has to be a string,

Answer (score 5):

For Julia 1.0 the syntax is:

`lpad(s, n::Integer, p::Union{AbstractChar,AbstractString}=' ')`

The example is therefore:

```
julia> lpad(4, 3, '0')
004
```

Comment: Thanks! Docs link: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.lpad

Answer (score 2):

There is also `@printf("%03i",4)` using [Printf.@printf](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/)